# Forcefully display a empty layout and then fill it with data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I am developing a new app for android 2.2(Froyo), I need to know how to forcefully display a leyout before loading it with dynamic data. I have a LinearLayout with a empty List, wen the appropriate menu is selected I load it with dynamic data which takes some time to load, but wat happens is the screen is empty till the layout is filled with data. I need to display the  empty layout which has ly title and show a ProgreesDialog till the list is filled with data. Here is my Activity class.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.deals);
     loadDeals();//fills the list with data(URL call)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user AsyncTask for loading data. During which you will be able to show ProgressDialog as well

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Use AsynchronousTask Class  and call loadDeals() from doInBackground Method.Just capture the data on that method.Then work ur UI in postExecute method.It will solve your problem